# "retriggering" Midi note in AudioKit

Tags: swift, audiokit

I'm working on a toy with multiple "touch areas" which serve as inputs to my synth.

Using an oscillatorBank I can start and stop notes easily.

In regular keyboards there's only 1 key for each Midi note, so "retriggering" a note requires the musician to lift their finger, even if only briefly allowing one to call .stop() and then .start() on the note.

The scenario I'm working on is when the note is held down, but is then triggered again on another "touch area". Could I somehow "retrigger" the "attack" sound for that note? Should I start and stop the player? Ideally I would call

```
oscillator.restart(noteNumber: )
```

but that doesn't exist that I know of.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a simple wrapper for stop(noteNumber:) and start(noteNumber:) that you could set up in an extension.

Comment: So I ended up doing as you suggest, but my solution was simply to call stop() and then set a timeout to start playing again 0.02 seconds later. It should work for my purposes, but not sure if there's a better way.